# Why does ActiveModel::Errors.new(self) not work with length, but count and size methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I worked with `ActiveModel::Errors` in Rails 5, and did some comparison in `count`, `length`, `size` method, I found that

```
ActiveModel::Errors.new(self).count  ==> 0 #result

ActiveModel::Errors.new(self).length ==> undefined method `length' #error

ActiveModel::Errors.new(self).size   ==> 0 #result
```

I tried to find the reason, but I can't.
Please help me why `length` doesn't work, but `count` and `size` work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because [`ActiveModel::Errors`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) simply does not implement a method called `length`.

If you a want a `Hash` from the object so in order to use `count`, `length`, and `size`, convert the `ActiveModel::Errors` object to a `Hash` using [`.to_hash`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-to_hash)

Leverage the [Rails documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/) to help explore classes and utilities available in Rails.